# How to configure connection pool in IIS?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, iis, connection-pooling

I have a 3 tier application Client(WinForm) - business(WebServices on IIS 7.5) and DataBase(SQLServer 2008 R2).

At present, when necessary I create a SqlConnection in this way:

```
public static SqlConnection getConnection()
{
      string conn = string.Empty;
      conn = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["quality"].ConnectionString;
      SqlConnection aConnection = new SqlConnection(conn);
      return aConnection;
}
```

How should I take the connection from a connection pool and configure it in the IIS ?

Comment: Do you have a Java background? It seems like it.

Comment: Yes my question derived by precedent experience with java web applications :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Connection pooling is automatic in ADO.NET. Most likely you don't need to know that it exists. Your code is fine. Be sure to dispose of the connection when you're done.

The International Space Station has nothing to do with this. Neither has IIS.